# how to close all panes but the current pane in tmux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I have a key bound to setup panes to my liking, but sometimes things get messed up or out of hand and I want to close all the panes and rerun the script. Is there a simple `tmux` command to close all panes except the one I am currently in?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the "kill-pane" command.

```
 kill-pane [-a] [-t target-pane]
               (alias: killp)
         Destroy the given pane.  If no panes remain in the containing window, it is also destroyed.  The -a option kills all but the pane given with -t.
```

So, for example if you want to kill all the panes except for pane 0:

```
kill-pane -a -t 0
```

If you don't know what you pane numbers are you can use the "display-panes" command:

```
 display-panes [-t target-client]
               (alias: displayp)
         Display a visible indicator of each pane shown by target-client.  See the display-panes-time, display-panes-colour, and display-panes-active-colour
         session options.  While the indicator is on screen, a pane may be selected with the '0' to '9' keys.
```

Comment: Thanks I did end up using kill-pane but I was having trouble getting it to work all the time.  What I ended up doing was spliting the window (split-window-h) that way I could be sure there was more than 1 pane, then I did a (break-pane -d) to move my current frame to a new window in the background.  Then I do kill-window.  That way I will be in a pane in a new window (the only one).

Comment: @DigitalPowers I like your solution, but sometimes it can make the split pane hard to find. Especially if you close a lot of panes. Since I was binding to a key, I used the hacky option of "enough" `swap-pane -U` commands to move the pane to position 0, and then `kill-pane -a -t 0`.

Comment: Note: `tmux kill-pane -a` kills all except the current pane.  You don't need to specify the `-t` target if you like the current pane.

Answer (score 9):

There is also "^b !" according to http://www.dayid.org/os/notes/tm.html (I also tried it and it worked for me)

Comment: hey! it looks like it works, but what it actually does is move that pane to a new "window" - kind of divorces it from the parent window - so the other panes still exist, they're just in a different window.